# New data not persisting to Rails array column on Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a user model with a friends column of type text. This migration was ran to use the array feature with postgres:

```
add_column    :users, :friends, :text, array: true
```

The user model has this method:

```
def add_friend(target)
  #target would be a value like "1234"
  self.friends = [] if self.friends == nil
  update_attributes friends: self.friends.push(target)
end
```

The following spec passes until I add `user.reload` after calling `#add_friend`:

```
it "adds a friend to the list of friends" do
  user = create(:user, friends: ["123","456"])
  stranger = create(:user, uid: "789")
  user.add_friend(stranger.uid)
  user.reload #turns the spec red
  user.friends.should include("789")
  user.friends.should include("123")
end
```

This happens in development as well. The model instance is updated and has the new uid in the array, but once reloaded or reloading the user in a different action, it reverts to what it was before the `add_friend` method was called.

Using Rails 4.0.0.rc2 and pg 0.15.1

What could this be?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suspect that ActiveRecord isn't noticing that your `friends` array has changed because, well, the underlying array reference doesn't change when you:

```
self.friends.push(target)
```

That will alter the *contents* of the array but the array itself will still be the same array. I know that this problem crops up with the [postgres_ext gem](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext#usage-notes) in Rails3 and given [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6954):

> String attribute isn't marked as dirty, when it changes with `<<`

I'd expect Rails4 to behave the same way.

The solution would be to create a new array rather than trying to modify the array in-place:

```
update_attributes friends: self.friends + [ target ]
```

There are lots of ways to create a new array while adding an element to an existing array, use whichever one you like.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the issue might be your use of `push`, which modifies the array in place.

I can't find a more primary source atm but [this post](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/09/18/rails-4-sneak-peek-postgresql-array-support.html) says:

> One important thing to note when interacting with array (or other mutable values) on a model. ActiveRecord does not currently track "destructive", or in place changes. These include array `push`ing and `pop`ing, `advance`-ing DateTime objects. If you want to use a "destructive" update, you must call `<attribute>_will_change!` to let ActiveRecord know you changed that value.

Comment: The use of `<attribute>_will_change!` worked easily for me, and seems to read decently well in the code. It has the benefit (I think) that all the changes to the array attribute happen in-memory and don't cause a database query for every change to the array. The tradeoff is, of course, that you need to mark the attribute as changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Postgresql array type, you'll have to comply with its format. From [Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) the input format is

```
'{10000, 10000, 10000, 10000}'
```

which is not what `friends.to_s` will return. In ruby:

```
[1,2,3].to_s => "[1,2,3]"
```

That is, brackets instead of braces. You'll have to do the conversion yourself.

However I'd much rather rely on ActiveRecord serialize (see [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class)). The database does not need to know that the value is actually an array, that's your domain model leaking into your database. Let Rails do its thing and encapsulate that information; it already knows how to serialize/deserialize the value.

Note: This response is applicable to Rails 3, not 4. I'll leave here in case it helps someone in the future.

Comment: AFAIK Rails 4 supports PostgreSQL arrays out of the box. And `serialize` is nasty when you need to query on the thing you're serializing.

Comment: Not using a pg array prevents the use of powerful multidimensional GINs