# Mongoid 4 update array attribute in a document

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

What is the mistake in this code for not be able to update an array within a document?

Model

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created

  field :myarray, type: Array

end
```

Controller

```
def add_item
        @foo = Foo.find_by(uuid: params[:uuid])
        unless @foo.nil?
            unless @foo.has_attribute? :myarray
                @foo[:myarray] = Array.new
            end
            @foo[:myarray] << params[:item]
            @foo.save
        end
end
```

I am using Rails 4 with MongoId 4 and if I do `p @foo` before `@foo.save` I can see @foo correctly changed but for any reason the update is not persisted.

Comment: What if you `@foo[:myarray] += [ params[:item] ]` instead?

Comment: This works! but I can't understand why it is necessary instanciate again the array for track the change in mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this:

```
@foo[:myarray] << params[:item]
```

You're modifying the `myarray` array in-place so Mongoid probably won't recognize that it has changed. Then when you say `@foo.save`, Mongoid will look at `@foo` to see what has changed; but the array reference in `@foo[:myarray]` won't change so Mongoid will decide that nothing has changed and `@foo.save` won't do anything.

If you force a new array reference to be created by saying:

```
@foo[:myarray] += [ params[:item] ] # Or anything else that creates a whole new array
```

then Mongoid will notice that `@foo[:myarray]` has changed and `@foo.save` will send the change down to MongoDB via `$set` operation on the underlying document.

This looks like the Mongoid version of this ActiveRecord problem with PostgreSQL array columns:

> [New data not persisting to Rails array column on Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17283854/479863)

The rule of thumb is "don't edit mutable values in-place, create whole new values instead: copy, edit, replace". That way you don't have to worry about manually managing the "is dirty" flags.