# How to use Rails #update_attribute with array field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Each question has an array of tags.

```
schema.rb:

create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "tags", default: [], array: true
```

How to atomically append to tags?

How to prevent dups within the array?

I tried `question.update_attribute tags: tags << :ruby`, but this doesn't work.

Rails 4.17 and Postgres.

EDIT: This seems to have been fixed in Rails 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `update_attribute` is going to be useful as it will replace the array with the new value rather than append to it (but see better explanation below in --Update-- section).

I'm not sure what best practices are here, but this should work to just add something if it isn't already there:

```
question.tags << :ruby unless question.tags.include?(:ruby)
question.save
```

I would write a custom method on the Question model to manage adding tags and checking for uniqueness:

```
def add_tag(tag)
  if tags.include?(tag)
    # do whatever you want to do when tag isn't unique
    p "#{tag} is already in tags!"
  else
    tags << tag
    save
  end
end
```

Then call it with `question.add_tag(:ruby)`.

--------------------  Update -----------------------

If this doesn't work, there could be an issue with ActiveRecord not recognizing the field has changed (although it seems to work OK in Rails 4.2).

These links explain the issue:

[New data not persisting to Rails array column on Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283854/new-data-not-persisting-to-rails-array-column-on-postgres)

http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/28/rails-4-and-postgres-arrays/

As they explain, you can use `update_attribute` here, but you need to replace the entire array rather than push a value onto it, like this:

`question.update_attribute(:tags, question.tags << tag)`

You should also be able to force ActiveRecord to consider the attribute updated by including `will_change!` like this:

```
def add_tag(tag)
  if tags.include?(tag)
    # do whatever you want to do when tag isn't unique
    p "#{tag} is already in tags!"
  else
    tags_will_change!
    tags << tag
    save
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually wrote this method. But it doesn't work for some reason. Apparently ActiveRecord can't update an array field from within the model. However, it does work from the controller.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what the trouble is -- were you calling it on a question object or the model class? I did a quick test in rails console on an object and it seemed to work. The use case I was picturing was an instance method on the model that is called in the controller like: `question = Question.find(params[:id]` then something like `question.add_tag(params[:tag])`.

Comment: I called it on the question object. Did `question.add_tag` work for you? I guess there could be something else going on because the code in `add_tag` works in the controller, but not when calling `add_tag` on the object. It is strange because updating other fields works when calling `add_tag` on the object.

Comment: Another strange thing is that the `save` method returns true, but the record is not updated. So I think there is an issue with ActiveRecord and array fields.

Comment: That does sound strange. I was able to get it working both in the console and by calling through a controller. I'm using Rails 4.2/postgres 9.3.5. Schema for tags is:  `t.text     "tags",       default: [],              array: true`. Not sure what's going on. If you want to post the updated model/controller code, I'll take a look and see if it is different from mine.

Comment: I have a Rack app, instead of Rails. So that is one possible cause.  `self.tags << tag; save` and will not update the tags field. It will update other fields.

Comment: Interesting... I did a little more research, and now I'm surprised my way is working for me. Possibly it's a recent Rails or ActiveRecord update, but I couldn't find it. Anyway, check out these links for different approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283854/new-data-not-persisting-to-rails-array-column-on-postgres or this one: http://paweljaniak.co.za/2013/07/28/rails-4-and-postgres-arrays/ -- will add an edit to the answer as well.