# Adding to hash value in hstore for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, hstore

I have my app setup to run ajax when a video is done watching. The ajax calls a User#action below. The problem is, when it is first run, it works and adds {"timestamp"=>"1"} but it never updates to {"timestamp"=>"1,1"}. Is there something I am missing? Can I not update the value in an hstore hash?

```
# Increases User's workouts after video is watched
    def increase_workouts
      @user = current_user
      if logged_in?
        if @user.newworkouts[Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_sym] == nil
          @user.newworkouts[Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_sym] = "0"
        end
        @user.newworkouts[Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_sym] += "," + "1"
        @user.save
        render(json: { message: "Workouts increased" }, status: :ok) and return
      else 
        render(json: { message: "Workouts increased" }, status: :ok) and return
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ActiveRecord isn't realizing that you've changed `newworkouts`. If you do this:

```
h = { }
h[:k] = 6
```

or this:

```
h = { :k => 11 }
h[:k] = 6
```

then `h` itself hasn't actually changed, its contents have changed but `h.object_id` is the same before `h[:k] = 6` as it is after. Similar things can happen with [PostgreSQL array columns and ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284779/479863) so `hstore` suffering similar issues wouldn't be surprising.

The solutions should be the same as with arrays:

1. Really change the hash.

   ```
   w = @user.newworkouts.dup
   # update `w` as needed...
   @user.newworkouts = w # Replace the reference
   @user.save
   ```
2. Manually mark it as dirty.

   ```
   # Update @user.newworkouts as you are now...
   @user.newworkouts_will_change! # Mark it as dirty.
   @user.save
   ```

I'd also recommend burying that login in a method on your model, then you could just say `@user.add_workout_at(Time.now)` in your controller and not have to worry about the ugly details of the internal representation.

You might also want to switch from `hstore` to `jsonb` for this column, then you could use an array as the value (`{"timestamp": [0,1]}`) rather than some sort of CSV-in-a-string like you're currently doing.