# Log changes from both attribute= and Array.push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

That ActiveModel::Dirty doesn't cover Array.push (or any other modify-in-place methods, as I've read extremely recently) for attributes pertaining to, say, postgres arrays is [pretty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283854/new-data-not-persisting-to-rails-array-column-on-postgres) well-established. For example, if an Apple model has an array Apple.seeds, you'll see the following in a Rails console.

```
johnny = Apple.new()
# => <Apple #blahblahblah>
johnny.seeds
# => [] (assuming [] default)
johnny.seeds << "Oblong"
# => ["Oblong"]
johnny.changed?
# => false
johnny.seeds = []
johnny.seeds += ["Oblong"]
# => ["Oblong"]
johnny.changed?
# => true
```

So you can use two different ways of changing the array attribute, but Rails only recognizes the one that uses a setter. My question is, is there a way (that won't mangle the Array class) to get push to behave like a setter in the context of an ActiveRecord object, so that `johnny.seeds << (x)` will reflect in `johnny.changes`?

(On my end, this is to prevent future developers from using push on array attributes, unwittingly failing to record changes because they were not aware of this limitation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with any column with a mutable object, not just Array objects.

```
seeder = Apple.first
seeder.name
=> "Johnny "

seeder.name << " Appleseed"
seeder.changed?
=> false
```

You're better off leaving a note for future developers, but otherwise you can consider replacing the `changed?` method

```
class Apple

  alias_method 'old_changed?', 'changed?'

  def changed?
    return old_changed? if old_changed?
    return (seeds.count > 0) if new_record?
    return seeds != Apple.find(id).seeds
  end

end
```

However, note that just because `changed?` comes back`true`, does not assure you that fields with unchanged object_ids will be updated in `update_attributes`... you may find that they're not.  You might need to hire competent rails developers who understand these pitfalls.